# Using schedule task(@schedule) in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

Hello am working on a cron job and would like to schedule the task to run every 2 minute,the problem is instead of 2 minutes its starts around 1min 20sec.this is the cron schedule I have

```
  @scheduled
  (cron="${followed_forum_task_
  crown_expression} ")
```

Then in my application.property file I have

```
  followed_forum_task_
  crown_expression = 0 0/2 * * * ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 0, fixedRate = 2*1000*60)`

instead of cron expression.